# Creating a layout programatically using XML elements

Tags: android, xml, view

I've programmed one of my layouts programatically. And when I tried to implement it in XML I couldn't make it work. It crashes with NullPointerException and I really do not know why.

This is my XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/canal_1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="canal1_Click"
    android:src="@drawable/pestanya_seleccionada" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And what I'm trying is:

```
ImageView canal1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* layout prinicpal */
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    canal1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.canal_1);
    relativeLayout.addView(canal1);
    setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
}
```

It crashes at `relativeLayout.addView(canal1);`

I don't why this fails. In my head everything should run fine.

Thanks for reading and hope you can help me ;)

Kind regards,
Raúl

Answer (score 0):

You have not set content of the xml layout to the screen and you are finding the id of the ImageView. This is causing NPE.

```
 canal1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.canal_1);
```

The above statement will cause nullpointerexception since you have not set the layout and your are trying to find the id form the defined in the xml file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activty_main);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
//add other ui elements to the root layout ie  RelativeLayout
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"// relative layout id
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/canal_1"
android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:onClick="canal1_Click"
android:src="@drawable/pestanya_seleccionada" />
</RelativeLayout>
```